# Orthogonal Complement and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q=\text{span}(\{q_1,q_2,q_3\})$ be a three dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. How do you show that the orthogonal complement of $Q$ is one-dimensional?

Comment: never mind, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

It is just because if $Q\oplus W=E$ and the space is finite-dimensional,  the union of a basis of $Q$ and a basis of $W$ is a basis of $E$, whether the direct sum is orthogonal or not. In other words:
$$\dim Q+\dim W=\dim E.$$